# How can I get full_join in dplyr to preserve data.tables?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm merging two data.tables using `dplyr`'s `full_join` like so:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(90088)
dt1 <- data.table(id = 1:10, var1 = sample(20:30, 10, replace = T), key = "id")
dt2 <- data.table(id = 1:10, var2 = sample(40:50, 10, replace = T), key = "id")

both <- full_join(dt1, dt2)
```

But the outcome is a data.frame, not a data.table.

```
class(both)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

I'd like to be able to take advantage of the speed of data.tables later in my code (ideally using `dplyr`).  Is there some option in `full_join` to preserve data.tables, or do I have to merge using the `data.table` syntax?

Comment: `dt1[dt2]` not good? ofcourse with `setkey(dt1, id); setkey(dt2, id)`

Comment: @ExperimenteR binary join can't perform a full join. If `df1` will be bigger than `df2` your code will return wrong result

Comment: @Jake, if you want to preserve the `data.table` class just use `merge(dt1, dt2, all = TRUE)`. `merge` has a `merge.data.table` method, see `methods(merge)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [latest dplyr docs (currently v0.4.1)](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf), the underlying join methods for data.table (`join.tbl_dt`) do not yet support the `full_join()`, unlike the data.frame methods (`join.tbl_df`).

My searches on the [dplyr github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) suggest there is not currently an outstanding feature request for this. My suggestion is therefore to raise a request if you'd like to see it implemented, and use `merge` in the interim.